# Regex find string by starts from

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to edit text with regex from:

```
“isLarge: ‘aaaa bb-b ccc’”
```

to:

```
“'lg:aaaa lg:bb-b lg:ccc‘“
```

I've founded solution to replace all whitespaces in quotes (https://regex101.com/r/ZrA1MP/1) but now I need this regexp work only when string starts with "isLarge: "

Comment: are u using php??

Comment: You say the string needs to start with isLarge but this string doesn't start with isLarge. It belongs to the key isLarge which regex knows nothing about. You'll need more then just Regex to fix this issue (key conditional + regex replacer)

Comment: Please clarify your question. I've read it 6 or 7 times and it's still not clear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Is this data by any chance coming from JSON?  As @Spidy points out, if you know the data is JSON, it might be easier to just pull out that key.

Comment: This is not data from JSON. This is webstorm IDE replace with regex. It works like string. 

Just trying to replace data format. 
So I only need pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous regex was flawed as it could match a space in the following string `isLarge: aaaa bb-b ccc dd-d -ee',`. The following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZrA1MP/2) works:

```
(?<=^isLarge: [^']*'[^']*) (?=[^']*'[^']*$)
```

- `(?<=^isLarge: [^']*'[^']*)` First it checks if the space is preceded by `isLarge:`  + any number of characters that's not a quote then a quote + any number of characters that's not a quote.
- `(?=[^']*'[^']*$)` then it checks if it's followed by a quote.

## Edit

```js
reg = /(?<=^isLarge: [^']*'[^']*) (?=[^']*'[^']*$)/gm;
str = "isLarge: 'aaaa bb-b ccc dd-d -ee',\nisLarge: aaaa bb-b ccc dd-d -ee',\nisMedium: 'aaaa bb-b ccc dd-d -ee'";
r.test(str)
// true
str.replaceAll(r, " lg:").replaceAll("isLarge: ",'');
// "'aaaa lg:bb-b lg:ccc lg:dd-d lg:-ee',
// aaaa bb-b ccc dd-d -ee',
// isMedium: 'aaaa bb-b ccc dd-d -ee'"
```

If the pattern is not working it's probably because the regex engine doesn't support a lookbehind with non-fixed width. the solution would be to capture the `[^']*'[^']*` and show it again in the replace scheme i.e:

```
(?<=^isLarge:)([^']*'[^']*) (?=[^']*'[^']*$)
```

and then use `$1` in the replace string to keep it i.e : `"$1 lg:"`

Comment: Sounds good, but does’t work. Pattern error. Could you please check again?

Comment: @Artur you mentioned that u're using `js`. Javascript supports the first regex while webstorm IDE might not support it. I edited the answer after seeing ur comment

Comment: you are right. My bad. Webstorm supports php regex, not javascript. 

Is it possible to make this your regex work with php? https://regex101.com/r/ZrA1MP/2

Comment: @Artur the update contains a version that'll work with php regex.